# Why was archive.is question deleted?

Tags: support, bug, specific-question

Why was the [archive.is](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/135222/35808) ([cached](http://web.archive.org/web/20191005132729/https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/135222/why-does-1-1-1-1-not-resolve-archive-is/135223)) question deleted without a trace?  (Apparently, " deleted by Sathyajith Bhat♦ 6 hours ago ".)

It's been heavily upvoted (75+ for question and top answer each), only a couple of gmail experts disagreed with the question, citing reasons that don't even apply to the question, and it was all deleted by the mods without even providing any sort of feedback?

What sort of community is this?  There's dozens of questions about Gmail and other sites not working or having their own quirks, some of which likewise prevent using the app at all (we even have a [dns](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dns) tag here for DNS-related questions, apparently — 24 questions tagged), why is it that a single question about bootstrapped startup webapp that has to be deleted?  Does this have to do with content censoring?  What happened with the idea that disagreeing with the content of the answer should result in a downvote, not deletion?

Comment: I didn't delete the question - not sure why it's attributed to me. I've asked the question in the mod chat and sent an email to developers to check in on this.

Comment: @SathyajithBhat, if you didn't delete it, couldn't you undelete it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per mod making a comment on this very meta question above, the original was deleted by mistake yesterday:

> ﻿﻿I didn't delete the question - not sure why it's attributed to me. I've asked the question in the mod chat and sent an email to developers to check in on this. – Sathyajith Bhat♦ 16 hours ago

[It has since been restored earlier today.](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/334793/221016)

Hopefully, this is the end of the saga.

Prior discussions:

- [Why questions about archive.is are offtopic, when archive.org, Gmail, YouTube, Google Search are all fine?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4706/35808)
- [34k views in less than a day? That's unprecedented](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4703/35808)