# Who are the current active moderators of WebApps in April 2023?

Tags: discussion, moderators

There seems to be only one active moderator in WebApps Stack Exchange. I wanted to ask to check that this is the case.

This link reveals that there are three users with moderator priveleges:  https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Please define "active moderator"

Answer (score 1):

The [current moderators](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) are, in alphabetical order:

- [ChrisF](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/users/21/chrisf)
- [Rubén](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/users/88163/rub%C3%A9n)
- [Sathyajith Bhat](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/users/310/sathyajith-bhat)

Here is a summary of when they were elected, and when their most recent post or comment was:

| Moderator | Elected | Latest post | Latest comment | Latest post in meta | Latest comment in meta |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ChrisF | 2011 | Aug 2019 | Oct 2018 | Oct 2021 | Dec 2020 |
| Rubén | 2020 | Mar 2023 | Apr 2023 | Apr 2023 | Apr 2023 |
| Sathyajith Bhat | 2012 | Dec 2022 | Dec 2022 | Nov 2022 | Jan 2023 |

(You can view the details about when they were elected at this link: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/election/ . I got the information about the comments from [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/webapps/query/1737794/last-comment-date-of-moderators) and [here](https://data.stackexchange.com/meta.webapps/query/1737862))

It looks like very few people nominated themselves for previous elections. Also, moderators in Stack Exchange communities are not required to win each election, they can stay on until they resign or staff members act. Elections are also not required to happen regularly, they happen whenever staff members and moderators decide. My post is not taking issue with this, I'm just trying to give context to this information.

I know that posts and comments aren't the only activity that the moderators do. But it's a good indicator.

### Conclusion:

To me, it looks like Rubén is currently active (daily), whereas ChrisF hasn't been active since October 2021, and Sathyajith Bhat hasn't been active since January 2023.

Comment: I am active, just not visibly so. I handle flags as I see them on weekly if not daily basis.

Comment: Posts and comments aren't necessarily that good an indicator of activity.  https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/users tells a slightly different picture.

Comment: ChrisF's above comment just made the above table obsolete :) You might want to add the source and date of the data retrieval. Also as Chenmunka mentioned, participation includes other things likes upvote/downvote, etc. By the other hand Mods activity goes beyond public participation.

Comment: I take all of your points. They are all good points. I am choosing to leave my post as is, as it was a snapshot of what I could see and how I felt at the time, but I hope readers read the comments as well and take that into consideration.

Answer (score -2):

Screenshot of [Web Applications Meta > Users > Participation > Month](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Participation&filter=month), taken in April 19, 2023

[image: Web Applications Meta Users Participation Month as of April 19, 2023]

The participation link has the following title:

> Users most active on this site (combined number of posts, votes, comments and edits)

The above screenshot shows 5 users having the `[mod]` user badgde, 3 are Community Moderators, 2 are Staff having moderatio privileges. Community Moderators are annotated with a red line.

The number below each user avatar corresponds to the reputation earned this since 2023-04-01 up to the current date. This is better for viewing the very recent participation than using SEDE as the later is updated weekly. I think that it shows all users that have participated but some data might shown until the user activity reach certain threshold.

The links below each user card are the tags of the posts where the user participated more. I don't know the reason about why some users doesn't have tags, but I assume that is it's to avoid disclosing on which posts the user have voted or did actions that might make some users "unhappy".

---

Please bear in mind that not all the moderator actions are publicly viewable.

I don't know what is the source of the data that you have included in the [self answer](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4998/88163). Probably it was the the user profile of each moderator. You might also would like to consider **Visited**. Note: The badges related to consecutive visits might not consider every visit. This might also happen with this value.

Some moderator actions can be viewed in the post history. You might want to make [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) or "bump" the existing one (see Related section) in [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com) to make that information easier to find.

By the other hand, Stack Exhange Data Explorer (SEDE, click the Data link at the site footer) could be used do analysis about user regular activity. AFAIK not all moderator actions are available in SEDE. Also you might ask a question about how to use it and what is available in [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com).

Note:

There have being cases where actions were wrongly attributed to a mod in the past in the post history. Here is one local case: [Why was archive.is question deleted?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4714/88163) from 2019.

### Related

#### Bugs

- [All post history events are now incorrectly showing as edits in post histories and timelines](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/369846/289691) (status completed, from 2021)

#### Feature Requests

- [Consecutive Day Count in profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/865/289691) (completed, from 2009)
- [Moderator actions in activity tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43704/289691) (no status tag, from 2010)

#### Discussions about Visited

Both are from 2010:

- [How do Stack Exchange sites track visited and consecutive days?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/69808/289691)
- [Visited Days vs Consecutive Days](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/54581/289691)

Comment: Hi Rubén. Which moderators do you think are currently active? I'm interested in hearing your opinion. That's the question that I asked, and your answer doesn't answer the question. Are you saying that it is impossible to know which moderators are active?