# 2023 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

[Moderator election #6](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/election/6) on Web Applications has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the new moderator is:

[image: Blind Spots]

They will be joining [the existing crew](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators) shortly — please thank them for volunteering and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/election/6) or [view a summary report online](https://www.opavote.com/results/5550453923250176).

Comment: Congratulations @BlindSpots, well deserved

Comment: Congratulations BlindSpots. Welcome as a community moderator!

Comment: @grg Thank you very much for your participation. Hopefully, you will keep your interest in participating here regularly.

Answer (score 3):

After this election, [the moderators of Web Apps](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4997/who-are-the-current-active-moderators-of-webapps-in-april-2023) are:

- [Blind Spots](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/users/197518/blind-spots), elected in 2023
- [ChrisF](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/users/21/chrisf), elected in 2011 (and never re-elected)
- [Rubén](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/users/88163/rub%C3%A9n), elected in 2020 (and never re-elected)

Why do we have moderators who weren't elected in 2023? That's the way Stack Exchange runs elections. Elections only select new moderators. Old moderators do not have to keep winning elections, they can choose to stay on as a moderator until they retire or the staff intervene.

This user is no longer a moderator, so he presumably retired from his position: [Sathyajith Bhat](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/users/310/sathyajith-bhat).

Only two candidates were [nominated in the 2023](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/election/6?tab=nomination), they are [grg](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/users/39590/grg) and [Blind Spots](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/users/197518/blind-spots) . 166 users voted.

Personally, I am glad that this election happened. It seemed to me that [they weren't enough active moderators before](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4998/24544), and this new batch of moderators hopefully will make good collective decisions. I wish there were more nominations and more new moderators, I think we all wish that. It's nobody's fault: Web Apps is a small community, and no one is obliged to nominate themselves for the responsibility of moderation. Thank you for volunteering for what can be a tough job. I say this as someone who has expressed frustrations, which the moderators have had to handle, and so I'm part of what makes the job tough. So I thank you additionally.

I wish this team the best! And I wish the Web Apps community the best!

Comment: "Elections only select new moderators. Old moderators do not have to keep winning elections, they can choose to stay on as a moderator until they retire or the staff intervene." – This is mostly true, with one main exception: a site's "graduation" election after it leaves public beta. In a site's graduation election, any pro-tem mods must re-nominate in the election (and be one of the winners) in order to stay on as mods.